# Is there any difference between "syllabify" and "syllabize"?

Tags: word-usage, word-meaning, american-english

When I translate *sillabare* with Google Translate, I get three verbs:

- Syllabify
- Syllabize
- Syllabise

The second and the third one are surely the American spelling and the British spelling.

The NOAD (from the Dictionary application I have on my Mac) just lists the first as derivatives of *syllabification* and describes it as verb; no other information is given.
The *Oxford Advanced User's Dictionary* (another application for Mac) doesn't even have an entry for those verbs.

Is there any difference (usage or meaning) between *syllabify* and *syllabize*, in American English?

Comment: Neither of them are very common words, but it looks like [*syllabify* is a lot more common than *syllabize*, and is getting more common while the other gets less common](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=syllabify%2Csyllabize&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Csyllabify%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Csyllabize%3B%2Cc0).

Comment: Ah! But in the vast, unexplored universe of the ngram also lurks the  inevitable  [_**syllabicate.**_](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=syllabify%2Csyllabize%2Csyllabicate&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Csyllabify%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Csyllabize%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Csyllabicate%3B%2Cc0)